# GAE Can't set up a Resident Instance, related to new Migrate Settings option?

Tags: google-app-engine

I am trying to create a couple of resident instances on a google app engine app hosted on appspot.com. I moved the idle instances slider from Auto down to 2. My understanding is that this will then create two "resident" instances and I should see those marked as Resident instead of Dynamic in the instances screen. But it isn't working, I am still only seeing 1 dynamic instance (this is a test with no traffic).

When I made and saved the idle instances change, I noticed what to me was a new option underneath that section, as follow :

> Performance Settings Migration for Modules
>
> Before you can modify performance settings across Modules, your
>   settings must be migrated. After the migration, performance settings
>   will be managed at the Module level, and changes must be made through
>   your app.yaml (Python) or appengine-web.xml (Java). Copy the settings
>   clause below to the appropriate file to preserve your performance
>   settings during the next update.

There is a button under this new section called Migrate Settings. When I click this the main screen just blanks, with the admin console menu options still available on the side. All very peculiar!

It also gives some setting for python and java to do the idle instances down to 2 change at the module config level. I stuck this into my appengine-web.xml and re-deployed but I am still only getting one dynamic instance.

Has anyone any experience of this "migrate settings" option?

Comment: Have you enabled billing ?

Comment: Sorry I should answered my own question. The billing was key, though it was quite confusing. I had billing set up on the account (for Cloud SQL) but in fact this billing profile doesn't apply to GAE, you have to set up a new one. The whole thing is a bit kludgy cos you can see all the options to turn on the resident instance and it just fails into a blank screen - urrrggggg! Setting up billing did indeed get it to work.